# Kotlin: How to perform an async function and wait for it to finish?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm writting my first app in Kotlin, so I'm pretty new to this. One of the functions it performs is to read something from an API, and then update the screen based on the result.

I have tried lots of things with the coroutines, but nothing seems to work.

For example, I have something like this:

```
private fun readAPI() {
    runBlocking {
        fun rAPI() = async {
            val api = "..."
            result = URL(api).readText()
        }
        println(tag, "Result: " + rAPI().await())
    }
}
```

And lots of different approaches. Nothing seems to work. In the above case I'm getting an exception "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException".

The only thig that has worked so far, is something using OkHttp3 as described here: https://rstopup.com/como-hacer-una-solicitud-a-la-api-de-kotlin.html (it's in Spanish, but you'll get the idea), and this works, it brings the API response, I parse it, fill in my sqlite3 database and so on. But, since I don't know when the API ends, I can't update the screen controls. And if I try to do it serially, I get an exception that only the thread which started the activity is the one that can update the activity or something like that.

I've seen, and follow LOTS of tutorials that talks about suspend functions, launch, etc., and they try to mimick an API call with `delay()`, those tutorials work perfectly, until I try to do a real API call.

So, can you point me to a full example on how to call an API with Kotlin, and then update some screen elements?

EDIT
I'm editing changing the fun by val:

```
runBlocking {
  val rAPI = async {
    val api = "..."
    URL(api).readText()
  }
  Log.w(tag, rAPI.await())
}
```

I got the "android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException" exception.

Comment: instead of `runBlocking` try `GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main)`

Comment: I tried that also :(

Comment: What happens? Also - what is this `result` variable? At this moment your `async` task returns nothing. Why do you declare `fun rApi()` instead of `val rApi`?

Comment: otherwise, you can create a new Thread T, call your API and manage callback inside, and wait the end with T.join()

Comment: @Pawel I just edited the question to show you the error

Comment: @Pawel: What do I have to do with the `GlobalScope`?

Comment: And GlobalScope.launch seems to be working!!! Thanks a lot!!! I'll do some more tests and let you know

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you want to use `coroutine`-`async` ways, you must tell main thread to waiting for you. you need to use `suspend` function or block to do this.

```
GlobalScope.launch {
    suspend {
        Log.d("coroutineScope", "#runs on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        delay(10000)
        withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
            Log.d("coroutineScope", "#runs on ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
    }.invoke()
}
```

result log

```
09:36:09.500 D/: #runs on DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
// 10 seconds later
09:36:19.678 D/: #runs on main
```

I think this should do the trick.

However I suggest you to understand how to use OkHttp/Volley by passing callbacks(with onSuccess and onFail or something) into that.
Or `Retrofit2` with `RxJava`to handle many of these issues.

**EDIT**
For the `Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize` error, replace the `withContext()` line with this

```
withContext(Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).asCoroutineDispatcher())
```

**EDIT**
Now don't use RxJava, use liveData/LiveEvent to implement the observer pattern

Comment: I tried this and got `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher is missing. Add dependency providing the Main dispatcher, e.g. 'kotlinx-coroutines-android'`

Comment: Try to use `coroutine` by add dependency : `implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1"`

Comment: OK, I added that dependency (I thought I had it), now I got `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Module with the Main dispatcher had failed to initialize`

Comment: I had the one you mentioned, I had to add `"org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.0.1"` also

Comment: I update my answer that might solve the error, suggest use the latest `coroutines-core` version.

Comment: It worked! Just needed to use 1.1.0 as they say here: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/932

Comment: I have `"org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.0"` and `"org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.1.1"`

Comment: That's interesting, never thought that we might need to downgrade. Can you please consider mark my answer as accepted :) ?

Comment: Sure, sorry I left the office without marking the question. Thanks a lot. I tried the GlobalScope early in the morning, but the withContext() made the trick

Answer (score 2):

In Kotlin you can convert callbacks to coroutines as described in this codelab https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-coroutines/#6