# How do I convert a response from a RESTful call to an array for a spinner adapter in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, adapter

I have a spinner in my app that should be populated with a list of suppliers. The spinner originally came from some example code and works perfectly using the fixed strings in the example. However, in my case, I get my list of values (suppliers) from an API. I can see the API being called correctly and the data returned in Logcat. I want to get the data from this response and use it as the object list for my spinner.

My question is two fold. Is there a more direct way of translating the response to the adapter, and if not, how do I translate reading the response into something the spinner will use?

My code looks like this:

```
var SupplierArray: MutableList<String> = ArrayList()

val suppliers = response.body()?APIResult!![0]

for (i in 0..suppliers.supplier.size - 1) {
    SupplierArray.add(suppliers.suppliers[i].supplier_name)
}
```

SupplierArray is declared in the class and the loop exists in the onResponse for the fucntion that calls the api.

Given that my response contains 3 suppliers, when I try to use SupplierArray for the adapter:

```
val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SupplierArray)
```

I get a null array. Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong please?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are waiting for the response from the restful call. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56763450/kotlin-how-to-perform-an-async-function-and-wait-for-it-to-finish).

Comment: The response is definitely returned complete. I write it out in its entirety to the logcat before defining the val suppliers. If I add Log.d("Each Sup:", suppliers.suppliers[i].supplier_name) inside the loop it writes each one correctly.